# Getting a value from json request in android

Tags: java, android, json, arrays

I need to get the JSON request and set it on the below design.

`Groupname1`

> `Staff1`
>
> `Staff2`

`Groupname2`

> `Staff3`

This is my json response :

```
 {"Response":   [{"complete_count":"11","assigned_count":15,"checked_count":"2","staff_firstname":"krish","staff_emp_code":"mmch23 y","staff_id":"29","group_name":"Technical- 1ty"},{"complete_count":"0","assigned_count":3,"checked_count":"0","staff_firstname":"Ravi","staff_emp_code":"MMCH050","staff_id":"38","group_name":"Technical- 1ty"},{"complete_count":"3","assigned_count":4,"checked_count":"0","staff_firstname":"mercy","staff_emp_code":"mmcho56","staff_id":"78","group_name":"Technical- 1ty"},{"complete_count":"0","assigned_count":1,"checked_count":"0","staff_firstname":"Sam ji","staff_emp_code":"Et","staff_id":"71","group_name":"test group"}],"success":1}
```

This is my code :

```
class My_WIReports extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        showDialog(DIALOG_LOADING);
    }
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_weekly_list_individual, "POST", params);
        Log.d("My Weekly Individual Reports: ", json.toString());
        try {
             success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {

                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json.toString());
                 groups = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_STAFFS);
                for (int i = 0; i < groups.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = groups.getJSONObject(i);
                    String groupname = c.getString(TAG_GROUPNAME);
                    String Staff_Complete_count = c.getString(TAG_STAFF_COMPC);
                    String Assig_Count = c.getString(TAG_STAFF_ASSC);
                    String Staff_F_name = c.getString(TAG_STAFF_NAME);
                    String Staff_Emp_code = c.getString(TAG_STAFF_EMPC);
                    String Staff_id = c.getString(TAG_STAFF_ID);
                    String  track_no = String.valueOf(i + 1);
                    map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    map.put(TAG_GROUPNAME, groupname);
                    map.put(TAG_STAFF_COMPC, Staff_Complete_count);
                    map.put(TAG_STAFF_ASSC, Assig_Count);
                    map.put(TAG_STAFF_NAME, Staff_F_name);
                    map.put(TAG_STAFF_EMPC, Staff_Emp_code);
                    map.put(TAG_STAFF_ID, Staff_id);
                    map.put(TAG_STAFF_NO, track_no);
                    groupList.add(map);

                }
             } else {
                groupList.clear();
                    }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
        return json.toString();
    }
```

Here am getting the result like below :

```
Technical- 1ty                  -(group_name - 1)
krish                             -(staff_firstname - 1)
Technical- 1ty                  -(group_name  - 1)
Ravi                               -(staff_firstname - 2)
Technical- 1ty                  -(group_name - 1)
Mercy                              -(staff_firstname - 3)
test group                      -(group_name - 2)
sam Ji                              - (staff_firstname -1)
```

But i need to get the result like below :

```
Technical- 1ty                    -(group_name - 1)
krish                               -(staff_firstname - 1)
Ravi                                -(staff_firstname - 2)
Mercy                               -(staff_firstname - 3)
test group                        -(group_name -2) 
sam Ji                              -(staff_firstname - 1)
```

Please give me a solution for this ?

How can i remove the duplicate  group_name values ?

Comment: Its clear from error that you are trying to convert Json Object into Json array,change it to json object

Comment: Is TAG_GROUP_NAME=="groupname" ?

Comment: Please tell us what the constants stand for

Comment: @Kartik_Koro yes exactly TAG_GROUP_NAME=="groupname" .Here i need to get the above values and set the values on the android client side.In the above code is not executing this line also:System.out.println("groups"+" "+" "+groups); its going to catch loop .pls check the code and give a solution for this ?

Comment: well the groupname field in your json corresponds to a JSONObject not a JSONArray. This will give the error you came across. But, I think you have made this mistake in multiple places, if you tell what field each of your final constants stand for, I can try to give you full solution.

Comment: @Kartik_Koro Please check my updated code and read my clear question  and give me a solution for this ?

Comment: Hey change map object
HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>> map = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>(); and then add it TAG_GROUPNAME as key and arraylist of "Staf" as value

Answer (score 0):

```
my point is:
1.get the values **from service to store vector or array** wat ever your wish...
2.get the **purticular value(groupname) from vector Using position..**
3.Eg:vector size 4...
3.In Adapter you should set 
**below code:**
for(int k=0;k<listvectorlocalsample.size();k++)
{
pojoitems=new SAmplepojo();
pojoitems=listvectorlocalsample.get(position);
String s1,s2l;
s1=pojoitems.getGroup_name().toString();
pojoss=listvectorlocalsample.get(positon+1);
s2=pojoitems.getGroup_name().toString();
if(s1.equalsIgnoreCase(s2l))
{
TextView.INVISIBLE;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So if I have understood correctly, you wish to print a group name, eg. "Technical- 1ty" and then print all of the members of that group.

You haven't included code for output in your question so I can only assume you are doing something like:

```
for(HashMap<String,String> map : grouplist){
    print map.get(TAG_GROUPNAME);
    print map.get(TAG_STAFF_NAME);
}
```

So obviously, it will print the group name of a staff member then his name.
What you would want is:

```
1) Store data of each staff member into a class called staff, instead of a HashMap.
2) Add each staff member to an ArrayList, say staff_members.
3) Sort staff_members by group name field of staff class.
4) Then with your ArrayList<Staff>staff_members (sorted by groupname )you can do the following:

String current_group="";
for(Staff staff_member: staff_members){
    if(!current_group.equals(staff_member.getGroupName()){
        current_group=staff_member.getGroupName();
        System.out.println(current_group);
    }
    System.out.println(staff_member.getFirstName());
}
```

I understand this may seem like alot of work for a simple job, but it is a good coding practice to properly have Classes for such things like your staff member instead of just a hashmap. Also if you want, you could make a constructor for your staff_worker class where you pass a JSONObject and it will assign proper values to the object. This will help give your code a neat and professional look, instead of having so many map.put() calls in your main code.